# Custom Layout that rounds the corners of its content

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a generic ViewGroup which can then be reused in XML layouts to round the corners of anything that is put into it.

For some reason `canvas.clipPath()` doesn't seem to have an effect. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Java code:

```
package rounded;

import static android.graphics.Path.Direction.CCW;
public class RoundedView extends FrameLayout {
    private float radius;
    private Path path = new Path();
    private RectF rect = new RectF();

    public RoundedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.radius = attrs.getAttributeFloatValue(null, "corner_radius", 0f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int savedState = canvas.save();
        float w = getWidth();
        float h = getHeight();
        path.reset();
        rect.set(0, 0, w, h);
        path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, CCW);
        path.close();
        boolean debug = canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
```

Usage in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rounded.RoundedView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    corner_radius="40.0" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</rounded.RoundedView>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The right way to create a `ViewGroup` that clip its children is to do it in the `dispatchDraw(Canvas)` method.

This is an example on how you can clip any children of a `ViewGroup` with a circle:

```
private Path path = new Path();

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    // compute the path
    float halfWidth = w / 2f;
    float halfHeight = h / 2f;
    float centerX = halfWidth;
    float centerY = halfHeight;
    path.reset();
    path.addCircle(centerX, centerY, Math.min(halfWidth, halfHeight), Path.Direction.CW);
    path.close();

}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int save = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(circlePath);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(save);
}
```

the `dispatchDraw` method is the one called to clip children. No need to `setWillNotDraw(false)` if your layout just clip its children.

This image is obtained with the code above, I just extended Facebook `ProfilePictureView` (which is a `FrameLayout` including a square `ImageView` with the facebook profile picture):

[image: circle clipping]

So to achieve a round border you do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    // compute the path
    path.reset();
    rect.set(0, 0, w, h);
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    path.close();

}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int save = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(save);
}
```

[image: round border clipping]

You can actually create any complex path :)

Remember you can call clipPath multiple times with the "Op" operation you please to intersect multiple clipping in the way you like.

NOTE: I created the Path in the `onSizeChanged` because doing so in the `onDraw` is bad for performance.

NOTE2: clipping a Path is done without anti-aliasing :/ so if you want smooth borders you'll need to do it in some  other way. I'm not aware of any way of making clipping use anti-aliasing right now.

**UPDATE (Outline)**

Since Android Lollipop (API 21) elevation and shadows can be applied to views. A new concept called [Outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html) has been introduced. This is a path that tells the framework the shape of the view to be used to [compute the shadow](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows) and other things (like *ripple effects*).

The default `Outline` of the view is a rectangular of the size of the view but can be easily made an oval/circle or a rounded rectangular. To define a custom `Outline` you have to use the method [`setOutlineProvider()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOutlineProvider(android.view.ViewOutlineProvider)) on the view, if it's a custom View you may want to set it in the constructor with your custom `ViewOutlineProvider` defined as inner class of your custom View. You can define your own `Outline` provider using a `Path` of your choice, as long as it is a [convex path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) (mathematical concept meaning a closed path with no recess and no holes, as an example neither a star shape nor a gear shape are convex).

You can also use the method [`setClipToOutline(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)) to make the Outline also clip (and I *think* this also works with anti-aliasing, *can someone confirm/refute in comments?*), but this is only supported for non-`Path` Outline.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I'm no longer an Android developer, this question is 3 years old, but this solution looks like the correct one. Stackoverflow delivers at last :)

Comment: I'm sorry you are no longer an Android Developer :) I'm curious tough. Why you marked the other answer as accepted answer if it wasn't right? :)

Comment: IIRC I got it working somehow based on that answer, but it wasn't elegant

Comment: Your solution work well to me, but when I apply ripple effect into the ViewGroup (foreground of FrameLayout), it doesn't hide the effect's background outside the path. Any idea for this, @DanieleSegato?

Comment: when I did this there was no elevation or Ripple effect. I think you need to define a custom Outline.

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows) for how to use Outlines

Comment: @DanieleSegato `setOutlineProvider()` and `setClipToOutline(true)` really apply anti-aliasing, I checked.

Comment: I think it's worth knowing that `setClipToOutline(true)` can cause massive performance hits - I used it on items in a RecyclerView, and the scrolling was incredibly laggy. Using the custom `ViewGroup` solution does not suffer from this issue, and performance is great

Comment: Luke, you need to enable hardware acceleration for it to work performantly i think. But I never used it on a scrolling list so not sure

Answer (score 23):

You can override the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
    public class RoundedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
        Path mPath;
        float mCornerRadius;

        public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public RoundedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipPath(mPath);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            mPath = new Path();
            mPath.addRoundRect(r, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Direction.CW);
            mPath.close();
        }

        public void setCornerRadius(int radius) {
            mCornerRadius = radius;
            invalidate();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Wow, why is this answer downvoted. It's the only solution that works for me. I would upvote twice if i could

Comment: exactly, perfect answer

Comment: Perfect answer, except that my draw method wasn't getting called unless I set setWillNotDraw(false).

Comment: The other answer didn't work, but this works. Why isn't this chosen as best answer? tnx anyway.

Comment: Amazing answer. Works perfectly. +1

Answer (score 3):

**onDraw** of FrameLayout is not **called** if Ur **Layout's background** not set;

You should override dispatchDraw;

Answer (score 2):

`ViewGroup` (and hence its subclasses) sets a flag indicating that it doesn't do any drawing by default. In source it looks somewhat like this:

```
// ViewGroup doesn't draw by default
if (!debugDraw()) {
    setFlags(WILL_NOT_DRAW, DRAW_MASK);
}
```

So your `onDraw(...)` probably doesn't get hit at all right now. If you want to do any manual drawing, call `setWillNotDraw(false)`.

Comment: `onDraw()` does get hit (I debugged), it is just something like `super.onDraw()` resetting the canvas's clip regions and tranformation matrix, or something... But if this is the wrong approach, what would be the right one?

Comment: willNotDraw has nothing to do with clipping, the problem he has is that he is doing that stuff in the onDraw() method.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to ask for onDraw to be called with setWillNotDraw(false); and set a value to mRadius then just do something like that :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mPath.reset();
    mRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.addRoundRect(mRect, mRadius, mRadius, Direction.CCW);
    mPath.close();
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

U need to override the drawChild() method to clip childViews.

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
    int flag = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(pathToClip);
    boolean result=super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    canvas.restoreToCount(flag);
    return result;
}
```

If u want to clip the background of the ViewGroup too,override draw() instead.like this

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    int flag = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(pathToClip);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(flag);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not just define a ShapeDrawable as the background of your layout and just change the corner radius of the drawable at runtime.

Comment: That wouldn't clip the corners of anything else that is contained within the layout... would it?

Comment: No, although you can set a padding to make sure it always has the rounded corner, I guess that's not what you want.I think the problem is not on canvas.clipPath but because it's used on a layout. Not sure what's the right way or even if there is one.