# android wipe animation when button bar slide up

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android, android-sliding

I'm trying to create slidingup animation in android application to change between two view of layout.

I've tried from [this tutorial](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
but the second screen didn't come like what I want.
I want the second layout to come like a wipe animation, like the following picture at the bottom

[image: Wipe Animatioin]

Comment: You will have to create custom view for this kind of animation. This can be achieved by making the view invisible but shown fully. Then as the handle(button) moves up show the view accordingly. You might want to refer the code of navigation drawer of android

Comment: Thank you for reply. Any tutorial to create this? Or can i change several code from <https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel>

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ab51002847ea3dcdc0ba14eb330ab9ec292a9789/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java

In the above code, focus on the **animateCollapsePanels** method

Comment: is there another way? sory, its to hard for me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a similar transition by using a clipping Path.  Because I didn't want my transition to rule out the use of Layouts in the clipped view, I implemented the clipping at the Layout level following this answer:  [Custom Layout that rounds the corners of its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517221/custom-layout-which-rounds-the-corners-of-its-content)

The clipping is no anti-aliased and you would need to do use instead PorterDuff and XferMode based solutions otherwise, but for a linear wipe animation like you're describing, clipping in the layout will achieve what you want.  Basically you're doing a linear reveal whereas the accepted answer I linked does a circular clip.