# child view not fix parent shape

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a round corners layout, now I want to add a child view (an Imageview) which matches the parent layout's height and width.

My problem is that the child view hides the round corners of the parent.

[image]

How can I constrain it inside the borders of the parent layout without using the margin property, so that the parent's round corners stay visible?

PS: I created round corners of parent layout by overriding the `onDraw()` method.

#### My code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, mpaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Post the ondraw code, the problem you're having could possibly be fixed by changing some stuff there. Does the image fill the complete imageview?

Comment: You could add some padding to your parent layout equal to the size of the corners.

Comment: @RolfSmit I posted my code, please help me

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you can put your child views into a `CardView`(in support v7), which is actually a `FrameLayout`, but it handle the corners by just set one line of code:

`app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"`

It can clip the corner with the radius you set no matter what the child views are.

Comment: Good one! Worked! In case, if you don't want shadow, set app:cardElevation="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add padding to the "rounded corner" view. This could be padding on all sides, bottom and top or left and right. Depending on what suits you the best.

I can't think of a more simple method than this. Your onDraw method looks fine, first the background than the child views.

Comment: I have to add padding in ondraw method of layout or childview,  my UI is created in code

Comment: Switch to xml layouts if you can, it's better maintainable.

Comment: cause I not only create layout in rounded corners , but also in many shapes

Comment: Why dont u use setPadding() in the constructor of your custom view?

Comment: Oh, why didnt I think about it earlier?, I'll try it, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

When you add a child to your `ViewGroup`, that child is being drawn on top of your `ViewGroup`, thus your rounded corner doesn't take effect.

In order to achieve your goal you have to perform clipping on a certain path in your layout. That sounds a bit complicated, but in fact it is not.

Essentially, you can understand **clipping** as "cutting off" some part from your layout.

```
RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
path = new Path();
path.addRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Direction.CW);

canvas.clipPath(path); // clipping here
// now anything that is outside this path will be "clipped", i.e. not drawn
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278056/1083957) for a complete source code.