# Draw custom Seekbar on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar, android-seekbar

I know there are a lot of libraries about that on GitHub and several questions on stack overflow about this argument. But no of those fit my needs.

I just need to draw something like this :

[image]

The progress line must be yellow with no thumb.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Android. What is wrong with my question? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: What have you tried? We are not a code writing service

Comment: Like I said I'm relatively new to Android. After trying to transform something that I found on Stack overflow I just realized that I cannot do It without a help on my specific case. I'm very sorry, I know It's a time loss question. But I have to ask it.

Comment: Try to google search something like, android draw custom view

Comment: But for someone who is really good to Android, doesn't it take few time to do something like this?

Comment: Can you please post something from the web that can I have a look at?

Comment: Guys, you do not have to write any code, just point him in the right direction explaining him what tool he has at disposition to achieve something similar. Not sure why downvoting ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to what I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517221/custom-layout-that-rounds-the-corners-of-its-content/32765455#32765455).

Just use a rectangle instead of a circle. Use on-size changed to compute the actual size of the rectangle and have a method to change the percentage and re-compute your rectangle size / recreate your path.

When you change the path you just have to call `invalidate()` to cause a re-draw.

Pseudo code:

```
public void setProgress(float progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
    refreshProgressBar();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    this.currentW = w;
    this.currentH = h;
    refreshProgressBar();
}

private void refreshProgressBar() {
    path.reset();
    // build your clipping path using progress / currentW / currentH
    path.close();
    invalidate();
}
```

You can do all with a single custom view or have 2 views on top of each other, the one containing the "fill" of the bar is clipped with the method I explained above.

Keep in mind the clipping happens on the Canvas. So if you you use a custom View just set the clipping before drawing the progress view and remove it when you are done (you can also directly draw the color in this case - but if you have a complex color pattern it may be easier to clip). If you use a clipping ViewGroup like in the link I gave you you'll have to build your layout accordingly so that the clipped view is only the progress one.

If you play a bit with math you may also be able to draw a path that match your art work and use it on a full color rectangle on top of your layout.

If you add together a Rectangle and a circle and then remove a circle (use the `OP` for adding / subtracting / multiplicating on the path) you should obtain a Path (shape) that resemble the one in your hand-drawing.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view for this.
Take a look at [Android creating custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Also, a more easy solution i can think of is to create a rectangular progress bar that occupes the whole width and draw on top on the middle, the play button

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks