# Drawing a custom Seek Bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to draw a custom seekbar. Below is the screenshot what i want to achieve.[image]

I have completed the seekbar, but the only problem is the thumb of the seekbar.
Following is the code of the thumb of my seekbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:tint="#22B7FF">
    <solid
        android:color="#22B7FF" />
    <size
        android:width="32dp"
        android:height="130dp" />

</shape>
```

I know how to draw vertical line
I want to draw the complete thumb in the drawable xml itself and not use view tag
I don't understand how to draw vertical line at the exact center of the thumb.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think it'd be better to create a custom view for it. Search "android draw custom view" on google. Also some examples for you: https://medium.com/@romandanylyk96/android-draw-a-custom-view-ef79fe2ff54b       http://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples

Comment: refer : -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928383/draw-custom-seekbar-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom seekbar (thumb size, color and background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)

Comment: @GowthamanM Not a duplicate. Please read the question

Comment: http://www.coderconsole.com/2015/03/android-seekbar-scrubber.html

Comment: @Pritish alternative solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for your Thumb. Edit the height and top bottom spaces of this accordingly :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is the main color -->

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#22B7FF" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="4.5dp"
        android:right="4.5dp"
        android:top="7dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="2.5dp"
        android:right="6.5dp"
        android:top="7dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="6.5dp"
        android:right="2.5dp"
        android:top="7dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```