# Building a round frame camera on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera2

I have built a camera app for android.The problem I am facing is making the camera frame to round instead of square or fullscreen.I tried to make the layout change its shape to circle but it didn't work.
The layout is->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#541358">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="350dp"
                 android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/backshape"
                 android:id="@+id/container">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: And this is the layout design]
[image: And this is how the camera looks like in actual(Notice the camera is still square, But I need it circular)]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32765455/1568530 this answer should do the trick

Comment: If you just wanna make it looks like a circle, you can consider overlap another  `ImageView` with a hollow-circle as `src` onto your camera's `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

your framelayout can be like this

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/backShape"></View>
    </FrameLayout>
```